# Old version of Telethon

Tags: python, pip, telethon

I have a problem. Last year I developed a Telegram Gateway that uses a socket and the Telethon library (installed through pip).
The problem is that this project is installed in an other pc and uses an old version of Telethon, foundamental to use thread (with the new Telethon version I can't use the thread with socket etc., it is changed).

I need to install the same Telethon version in order to use the same gateway.

In the pc, if I run the command:

**pip show telethon**

it shows the following message:

**You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.1.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via etc......**

Then, I need to install the same version of telethon (8.1.1).
But if I try to install it in an other pc, through this command:

**pip3 install telethon==8.1.1**

it prints the following red error message:
No matching distribution found for telethon==8.1.1

Why?
I really need to use the same version of telethon, in order to run the old gateway.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: P.S. in the pc with the older version of telethon, there is python 2.7.12. In the new computer (where I need to install the old version of Telethon) there is python 2.7.15rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is a message printed by pip telling you to consider upgrading pip itself. The version number you are looking for is printed below it:

```
$ pip3 show telethon
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Name: Telethon
Version: 1.6.2
Summary: Full-featured Telegram client library for Python 3
Home-page: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon
Author: Lonami Exo
Author-email: totufals@hotmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: rsa, pyaes
Required-by:
```